# swift i want to pass image selected from gallery to next view controller as link

Tags: ios, swift

hey everyone i'm new to swift. i just pass the picked image from gallery to the next view controller as a link.  heres some code --

```
 @objc func imageTapped(tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer)
{
    print("image tapped")
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary){
        print("Button capture")
        let imag = UIImagePickerController()
        imag.delegate = self
        imag.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary;
        imag.allowsEditing = true
        self.present(imag, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        uploadImage.image = pickedImage
    
    }
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

now i have the selected image in "pickedImage". and on click next button

```
    @IBAction func onClickNext(_ sender: Any) {
        let controller = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "secondViewController") as! SecondViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
}
```

how to pass this image (pickedImage) to next view controller

Answer (score 1):

In your case it seems the easiest would be to add a property on your `SecondViewController` which accepts your image. So something like

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var inputImage: UIImage?
    ...
```

Now you can use this property when you create the view controller and pass it to your navigation controller.

```
@IBAction func onClickNext(_ sender: Any) {
    let controller = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "secondViewController") as! SecondViewController
    controller.inputImage = uploadImage.image
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use above answer for navigation.
For url in didfinishPickingMediainfo:

```
 func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    print("I am in dismiss")

    if let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.editedImage] as? UIImage {
        //            self.addImage.image = image
        let imageUrl          = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.imageURL] as? NSURL
        var imageName         = imageUrl?.lastPathComponent
        guard let imageData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.75) else { return }

        
        
    }else{
        if let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {
            //            self.addImage.image = image
            let imageUrl          = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.imageURL] as? NSURL
            var imageName         = imageUrl?.lastPathComponent
            guard let imageData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.75) else { return }
            //                let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.2) as Data?

            
            
        }
    }
    
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil);
}
```

check the above code its for both Camera and Gallery image. check "imageUrl" variable